# Sampling concentration parameter of DP via Slice sampling?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, hierarchical-bayesian, dirichlet-process

Is there a published work which shows how sampling the Dirichlet Process's concentration parameter can be done via Slice sampling?

Comment: If anyone looked at it, it must be Radford Neal!